# Substring with large text file in java

Tags: java, substring, large-files

I have a text file(253 MB Size) and I write this code:

```
    String content = new Scanner(new File ("C:\\Users\\user1\\IdeaProjects\\untitled\\file")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

    System.out.println(content.substring(19,26));
```

but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:57)
at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:335)
at java.util.Scanner.makeSpace(Scanner.java:840)
at java.util.Scanner.readInput(Scanner.java:795)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1369)
```

for use substring function in large file, What can I do ...
please help me...

Comment: Launch Java with increased heap space: `java -Xmx1024M YourClass` or rewrite your program to read the file in chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems terribly ineffective to read the whole file, if you need only a 7-letter substring. It really depends on your file structure, but if you're certain that all you need are bytes from positions `19..26` then you could simply read those bytes using `RandomAccessFile`, e.g.:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(new File("..."), "r"); // "r" means 'open the file for reading'
raf.seek(19L); // or other position depending on your file structure
byte[] b = new byte[7]; // choose how big the byte-buffer should be - how long is the substring
raf.read(b); // read from file into the buffer
System.out.println(new String(b)); // create a String from the byte-buffer
```

Of course, you should choose a proper charset encoding when creating the String, depending on your input file, e.g. `new String(b, "UTF-8")`